# Gradle : buildSrc not reconized as a source folder. (How to configure in IntelliJ and/or Eclipse) ? (CustomTask)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I need de create CustomTask in my gradle project.
However the buildSrc directory is not reconized as a source code folder so I cannot debug and test easaly.

What is the way to do it ? (on IntelliJ and/or Eclipse) ?
[image]

You can see an example project here : https://github.com/marcelkobaingithub/stack-overflow-gradle-buildsrc

Answer (score 0):

Ok on intelliJ simply add gradle java plugin ... :)